# Not able to install any gem including SASS using RubyGems from terminal

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, compass

I am in need of using `Sass` in my web design projects. Whenever I want to install `Sass` using terminal an error appears as below:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/sass-3.4.19.gemspec.rz)
```

I've tried updating `SSL` certificate update as explained in [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/) and I still have the error.

Actually, once I want to access any gem, I confront the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of SSL security reasons, Try this Command
`gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/`

`Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]`

give `y`
and then give install command

**UPDATE:**

How to fix error and get back to https with ssl:

`gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/` - to temporarily remove secure connection

`gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/` - to add an insecure connection with ruby

`gem update --system` - now you will be able to update rubygems without SSL

after updating rubygems you can do this vice versa

`gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/` - to remove insecure connection

`gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/` - add secure connection

Now you're able to update gems using secure connection.

`gem update`

Comment: Check with my updated Answer, Hope this will work for u

Comment: Thank you so much. Works Fine